# Maven not able to find plugin descriptor

Tags: java, maven-2, apache-torque

Im trying to build a legacy project, which has dependencies like torque. When I try to execute the command `mvn torque:create-db`

But I see the following error

```
 D:\someproject\cps-rfq\someproject-new\someproject>mvn torque:create-db
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] FATAL ERROR
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] The plugin descriptor for the plugin Plugin [torque:maven-torque-plugin]
 was not found. Please verify that the plugin JAR D:\someproject\cps-rfq\lib\torque\ma
 ven-torque-plugin\3.3-RC3\maven-torque-plugin-3.3-RC3.jar is intact.
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Trace
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The plugin descriptor for the plugin Plugin [to
 rque:maven-torque-plugin] was not found. Please verify that the plugin JAR D:\IR
 DEV\cps-rfq\lib\torque\maven-torque-plugin\3.3-RC3\maven-torque-plugin-3.3-RC3.
 jar is intact.
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginM
 anager.java:360)
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyVersionedPlugin(De
 faultPluginManager.java:224)
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyPlugin(DefaultPlug
 inManager.java:184)
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.loadPluginDescriptor(Def
 aultPluginManager.java:1642)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(Defa
 ultLifecycleExecutor.java:1540)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.getMojoDescriptor
 (DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1787)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.segmentTaskListBy
 AggregationNeeds(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:462)
         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLi
 fecycleExecutor.java:175)
         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
         at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:6
 0)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
 java:39)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
 sorImpl.java:25)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
         at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
         at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)

         at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: < 1 second
 [INFO] Finished at: Sat Jun 29 11:56:10 IST 2013
 [INFO] Final Memory: 1M/15M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But I can see the `D:\someproject\cps-rfq\lib\torque\maven-torque-plugin\3.3-RC3\maven-torque-plugin-3.3-RC3.jar` file in the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the final release version like this:

```
mvn torque:maven-torque-plugin:3.3:create-db
```

Furthermore i would suggest to first try to delete the folder in your local repository:

```
D:\someproject\cps-rfq\lib\torque
```

And retry your build, cause it looks weired that the RC version has been in use instead of the release version.